# Javascript Date.UTC() function is off by a month?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I was playing around with Javascript creating a simple countdown clock when I came across this strange behavior:

```
var a = new Date(), 
now = a.getTime(),
then = Date.UTC(2009,10,31),
diff = then - now,
daysleft = parseInt(diff/(24*60*60*1000));
console.log(daysleft );
```

The days left is off by 30 days.

What is wrong with this code?

Edit: I changed the variable names to make it more clear.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20806052/1048572

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The month is zero-based for JavaScript.

Days and years are one-based.

Go figure.

**UPDATE**

The reason this is so, from the [creator of JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich), is

> JS had to "look like Java" only less so, be Java's dumb kid brother or boy-hostage sidekick. Plus, I had to be done in ten days or something worse than JS would have happened.

http://www.jwz.org/blog/2010/10/every-day-i-learn-something-new-and-stupid/#comment-1021

Comment: Nice quote, but Eich is talking about Integers there. Here is the part about Date, from the same source: *"I had help only for jsdate.c, from Ken Smith of Netscape (who, per our over-optimistic agreement, cloned java.util.Date -- Y2K bugs and all! Gosling...)"*

Comment: bruh i spent 2 hours on this

Answer (score 10):

As Eric said, this is due to months being listed as 0-11 range.

This is a common behavior - same is true of Perl results from localtime(), and probably many other languages.

This is likely originally inherited from Unix's localtime() call.
(do "man localtime")

The reason is that days/years are their own integers, while months (as a #) are indexes of an array, which in most languages - especially C where the underlying call is implemented on Unix - starts with 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but this is still a problem today (or a feature as some might say - and they are wrong).

JS is zero-based month, why? Because.

That means the months range from 0-11 (only the months, the others are normal)

How can you fix this? Add a month, obviously, BUUUUT:

Don't do this :

```
let date: Date = new Date();
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
```

Why you might ask? Because it won't work as expected, `Date` in JS is terrible.

You have to make a ... let's call it not so beautiful function to translate the JS date to a normal date

```
formatJsDateToNormalDate(Date date): string | null {
  if(date !== null) {
        const realMonth: number = date.getMonth() + 1;
        let month: string = (realMonth < 10) ? '0' + realMonth : String(realMonth);
        let day: string = (date.getDate() < 10) ? '0' + date.getDate() : String(date.getDate());
        
        return [date.getFullYear(), month, day].join('-');
  } else {
    return null;
}
```

Again, if you ask me this is the equivalent of hammering a screw, it's not the right way, but there is no right way here, it's a bug that has been going on for 27 years and more to come.

Answer (score -4):

```
date1 = new Date();
//year, month, day [, hrs] [, min] [, sec]
date1 = new Date.UTC(date1.getFullYear(),date1.getMonth()+1,date1.getDate(),date1.getHours(),date1.getMinutes(),date1.getSeconds());

date2 = new Date();
date2 = date2.getTime();

alert(date1)
alert(date2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what point you're making here, and the code doesn't run (`TypeError: function UTC() { [native code] } is not a constructor `).