# Javascript Date object - month misreporting?

Tags: javascript, date

As simple as this is I appear to be missing something in understanding the Date() object or im just too tired to see something obvious. Why does this javascript report the month wrong?
(It will report the month as **July** instead of June as written.)

```
<script>

var x = new Date(2013,6,27,0,0,0,0);
var today = new Date();

if (x>today)
  {
  alert("Today is before " + x);
  }
else
  {
  alert("Today is after " + x);
  }

</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in JS months go from `0` to `11`, see the [`Date Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)!

You have to change the code to this:

```
new Date(2013, 5, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: THanks @LightStyle I found that a moment or so after I posted - but your answer is correct so I'll select it :)

Comment: Well, good for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript counts the months starting from 0

Comment: But not days, just to be clear.

Comment: Only months, days and years as normal  :)

Answer (score 0):

**Please disregard, I failed to look a little deeper and the answer was already present on SO:**

[Javascript Date.UTC() function is off by a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507619/javascript-date-utc-function-is-off-by-a-month)

Thanks.