# javascript UTC timestamp convert to Date 1 month off

Tags: javascript, utc

I'm trying to do this:

```
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 8, 2));
console.log(d)
```

It is giving me Mon Sep 01 2014 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

It is always one month off. if i convert construct a timestamp using UTC, and construct that to Date

Any suggestion what might went wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript months are zero based

This is a duplicate question

Check this thread for more insight [Javascript Date.UTC() function is off by a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507619/javascript-date-utc-function-is-off-by-a-month)