# Why Date.UTC(2015, 08, 31) == Date.UTC(2015, 09, 01) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, utc

My script broke up after yesterday because both Date.UTC(2015, 08, 31) and  Date.UTC(2015, 09, 01) provides same timestamp 1443657600000.

This is the only pair of days which provide same result. what am I missing?

Comment: I get october from those imputs while converting it to date! :D 
https://jsfiddle.net/5oyyos2L/

Comment: September only has 30 days...

Comment: http://jsconsole.com/?Date.UTC%282015%2C%2008%2C%2031%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%29%3D%3DDate.UTC%282015%2C%2009%2C%2001%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%29 gives out true for equal, strangest thing I have seen recently

Comment: Note that numeric literals starting with `0` are supposed to be in octal notation! You should use `8` instead of `08`. (Asterisk: Javascript is not very strict about numbers outside the octal range, so it didn't actually happen to cause an issue...)

Comment: @deceze: Yeah, does it just treat them as decimal literals then?

Comment: @BoltClock Yup. If the digits are outside the octal range, it just interprets them as decimal. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates

Comment: I'm surprised you only noticed the one month offset *now*...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507619/javascript-date-utc-function-is-off-by-a-month

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The month parameter is zero-indexed. So 8 is actually september which only has 30 days. So it *flows over* to october.

Reference: [Date.UTC()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

Comment: Who the hell came up with an idea to zero index the month? Why haven't they zero-index the year? Because it's stupid! :D That's why they shouldn't have zero-index the month as well. I understand the hour and minutes are zero-indexed because there is no 60 on a clock... but there is 12th month on the calendar!! :D

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks, *guy who wanted an array of month names*! >:-(

Comment: @Jamiec Yep - it's better to make an illogical arguments of function instead of simply decrement the month value by 1 in the code? :) 
And "other side of the coin" - RTFM!! :)

Comment: @Mr.TK Im sorry that comment makes no sense. Are you telling me to RTFM? If so I did, thats how I know how javascript works!

Comment: @Jamiec I wasn't referring to You in any manners. I was just criticizing the way this function/class was made, and also that everybody who uses it should read manual. :)