# Date not showing correct in High Chart x-xis

Tags: php, json, date, highcharts

My `JSON`:

```
[{"date":"2016,07,01","coached":"0.00000000000000","non_coached":"1.07262272089762","delta":-1.0726227208976},{"date":"2016,06,24","coached":"0.00000000000000","non_coached":"0.64400560224090","delta":-0.6440056022409},{"date":"2016,06,17","coached":"1.13666666666667","non_coached":"0.41228898426323","delta":0.72437768240344},{"date":"2016,06,10","coached":"0.68866666666667","non_coached":"0.46050000000000","delta":0.22816666666667},{"date":"2016,06,03","coached":"0.68666666666667","non_coached":"0.19209103840683","delta":0.49457562825984},{"date":"2016,05,27","coached":"-0.03933333333333","non_coached":"-0.04332859174964","delta":0.00399525841631},{"date":"2016,05,20","coached":"0.01214285714286","non_coached":"-0.07948965517241","delta":0.09163251231527},{"date":"2016,05,13","coached":"0.30733333333333","non_coached":"-0.10541436464088","delta":0.41274769797421},{"date":"2016,05,06","coached":"0.20937500000000","non_coached":"0.00750704225352","delta":0.20186795774648},{"date":"2016,04,29","coached":"0.00133333333333","non_coached":"-0.10642559109875","delta":0.10775892443208},{"date":"2016,04,22","coached":"-0.25600000000000","non_coached":"-0.06736248236953","delta":-0.18863751763047},{"date":"2016,04,15","coached":"0.31375000000000","non_coached":"-0.05191489361702","delta":0.36566489361702},{"date":"2016,04,08","coached":"-0.28800000000000","non_coached":"-0.00908682634731","delta":-0.27891317365269},{"date":"2016,04,01","coached":"0.14466666666667","non_coached":"-0.01988522238164","delta":0.16455188904831},{"date":"2016,03,25","coached":"0.20000000000000","non_coached":"0.05398581560284","delta":0.14601418439716},{"date":"2015,12,25","coached":"0.01344827586207","non_coached":"-0.06062585034014","delta":0.07407412620221},{"date":"2015,12,18","coached":"0.26806451612903","non_coached":"-0.00484311050477","delta":0.2729076266338},{"date":"2015,12,11","coached":"0.25352941176471","non_coached":"-0.01641483516484","delta":0.26994424692955},{"date":"2015,12,04","coached":"0.15000000000000","non_coached":"0.00259002770083","delta":0.14740997229917},{"date":"2015,11,27","coached":"0.18500000000000","non_coached":"0.06243626062323","delta":0.12256373937677},{"date":"2015,11,20","coached":"0.20500000000000","non_coached":"-0.06820584144645","delta":0.27320584144645},{"date":"2015,11,13","coached":"0.28800000000000","non_coached":"0.14813559322034","delta":0.13986440677966},{"date":"2015,11,06","coached":"0.05097560975610","non_coached":"0.02680397727273","delta":0.02417163248337},{"date":"2015,10,30","coached":"0.25279069767442","non_coached":"0.13122392211405","delta":0.12156677556037},{"date":"2015,10,23","coached":"0.06536585365854","non_coached":"0.12291605301915","delta":-0.05755019936061},{"date":"2015,10,16","coached":"0.03487804878049","non_coached":"0.30552833078101","delta":-0.27065028200052},{"date":"2015,10,09","coached":"0.06000000000000","non_coached":"0.17649499284692","delta":-0.11649499284692},{"date":"2015,10,02","coached":"0.18186046511628","non_coached":"0.30160173160173","delta":-0.11974126648545},{"date":"2015,09,25","coached":"-0.04195121951220","non_coached":"0.32907246376812","delta":-0.37102368328032},{"date":"2015,09,18","coached":"0.17447368421053","non_coached":"0.26081447963801","delta":-0.08634079542748},{"date":"2015,09,11","coached":"-0.04069767441860","non_coached":"0.39883058470765","delta":-0.43952825912625},{"date":"2015,09,04","coached":"0.13073170731707","non_coached":"0.29857580398162","delta":-0.16784409666455},{"date":"2015,08,28","coached":"0.39302325581395","non_coached":"0.30868827160494","delta":0.08433498420901},{"date":"2015,08,21","coached":"0.13843137254902","non_coached":"0.25431578947368","delta":-0.11588441692466},{"date":"2015,08,14","coached":"0.18000000000000","non_coached":"0.21200328407225","delta":-0.03200328407225},{"date":"2015,08,07","coached":"0.37620000000000","non_coached":"0.18070000000000","delta":0.1955},{"date":"2015,07,31","coached":"0.35239130434783","non_coached":"0.17344208809135","delta":0.17894921625648},{"date":"2015,07,24","coached":"0.01840909090909","non_coached":"0.24440514469453","delta":-0.22599605378544},{"date":"2015,07,17","coached":"0.16108695652174","non_coached":"0.26153225806452","delta":-0.10044530154278},{"date":"2015,07,10","coached":"0.16166666666667","non_coached":"0.31383471074380","delta":-0.15216804407713},{"date":"2015,07,03","coached":"0.11671875000000","non_coached":"0.21704361873990","delta":-0.1003248687399},{"date":"2015,06,26","coached":"0.30638888888889","non_coached":"0.17638668779715","delta":0.13000220109174},{"date":"2015,06,19","coached":"0.37225352112676","non_coached":"0.24194221508828","delta":0.13031130603848},{"date":"2015,06,12","coached":"0.25636363636364","non_coached":"0.21017214397496","delta":0.04619149238868},{"date":"2015,06,05","coached":"0.17027027027027","non_coached":"0.21259375000000","delta":-0.04232347972973},{"date":"2015,05,29","coached":"-0.36263888888889","non_coached":"0.05622291021672","delta":-0.41886179910561},{"date":"2015,05,22","coached":"0.18888888888889","non_coached":"0.18983076923077","delta":-0.00094188034188},{"date":"2015,05,15","coached":"-0.05687500000000","non_coached":"0.12545592705167","delta":-0.18233092705167},{"date":"2015,05,08","coached":"0.20102564102564","non_coached":"0.15625570776256","delta":0.04476993326308},{"date":"2015,05,01","coached":"0.07525000000000","non_coached":"0.12190193164933","delta":-0.04665193164933},{"date":"2015,04,24","coached":"0.29610389610390","non_coached":"0.13772519083969","delta":0.15837870526421},{"date":"2015,04,17","coached":"0.01613333333333","non_coached":"0.03368916797488","delta":-0.01755583464155},{"date":"2015,04,10","coached":"0.21420289855072","non_coached":"0.05916018662519","delta":0.15504271192553},{"date":"2015,04,03","coached":"-0.01797297297297","non_coached":"-0.05907435508346","delta":0.04110138211049},{"date":"2015,03,27","coached":"-0.00767123287671","non_coached":"0.06102201257862","delta":-0.06869324545533}]
```

Just want to show the first 13 weeks of data.

This is my code to process the `JSON`:

```
          var series = [{name:'Coached',data:[]},{name:'Non Coached',data:[],stack: 'yes'},{name:'Opportunity',data:[],stack: 'yes'}],
      year, month, day;

        for(var i=0; i<13;i++){

            var d = response[i].date.split(",");
            year = d[0];
            month = d[1];
            day = d[2];
            var coached = parseFloat(response[i].coached);
            var non_coached = parseFloat (response[i].non_coached);
            var delta = parseFloat (response[i].delta);
            series[0].data.push([Date.UTC(year,month,day),coached]);
            series[1].data.push([Date.UTC(year,month,day),non_coached]);
            series[2].data.push([Date.UTC(year,month,day),delta]);
            alert(Date.UTC(year,month,day));
        }

              console.log(series);

      if(series.length){

       stacked_chart_eCo_prod.userOptions.series = series;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(stacked_chart_eCo_prod.userOptions);
        console.log(chart.series[0].data[0].options);
        console.log(chart.series[1].data[0].options);
        console.log(chart.series[2].data[0].options);

      }
```

This is the PHP code:

```
 stacked_chart_eCo_prod = new Highcharts.Chart({
      colors: ['#003399','#910000','#55BF3B'],
      chart: {
          renderTo: 'stacked_chart_eCo_prod',
          type: 'column'
      },

      title:{
          text:''
      },
           yAxis: {
              format: '{value:.2f}',


              title: {
                  text: 'Job Uplift'
              }
          },

      xAxis: {
              type: 'datetime',

             labels: {
                  format: '{value:%Y-%m-%d}',
                  align: 'right',
                 rotation: -30
              }
          },



          plotOptions: {
              column: {
                  stacking: 'normal'
                //  keys:['x','y','stack']
              }
          },

          series: []

  });
```

The date shown on the x-axis is wrong.
I have looked at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4azb64t7/2/) but no use. 
Any ideas what am I missing here?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/L5n6L27c/) is the issue. I think Date.UTC method is not working properly?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "wrong"? Everything looks right from what I can see.

Comment: @jlbriggs the first date should show for `april` but it shows for `May`

Comment: Date.UTC expects months to range from 0 to 11.  So when you have 4 representing April in your data, it's really being computed as May.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507619/javascript-date-utc-function-is-off-by-a-month

Comment: @Sualkcin it solved my issue. I just subtracted one from the month and all good. Thank you!