# Javascript date - month always increment

Tags: javascript

Hello I encountered strange behavior with javascript date. I show in this example:

```js
var date = new Date(2017, 07, 22);
console.log(date); //22. 8. 2017
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString()) //Tue Aug 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

Why is month always increment? Is normal behavior or its my problem? Thanks

Comment: It's not your problem:month
Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Date.UTC() function is off by a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507619/javascript-date-utc-function-is-off-by-a-month)

Comment: or [javascript is creating date wrong month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254333/javascript-is-creating-date-wrong-month)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript [**`Date`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)'s month  starts  from 0. So 7 is actually 8th Month which is August.

> month
>
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

Answer (score 1):

In the JavaScript `Date()` object, the the month is an integer, starting at `0`.

- `0` = January
- `1` = February
- `2` = March

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript date month starts form zero index only ie jan is 0 and december is 11[image]