# Weird behaviour from JS Date() object

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I want to represent the first of a given month, say 1st of Septemeber 2020. When I do this in my console, I get the below output:

```
$ node
> new Date(2020, 8, 1)
2020-08-31T23:00:00.000Z
```

How come it returns 2020-08-31 instead of 2020-08-01? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the representation is in UTC , while the date constructor uses the timezone of your browser, which is `+01:00`

Comment: It takes your timezone into account

Comment: Months are zero-based in JavaScript. 0 = January, 8 = September.

Comment: See also [Javascript Date.UTC() function is off by a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1507619/215552)

Comment: I believe OP is aware of the month indices

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Why do you say that? They entered `new Date(2020, 8, 1)` and expected `2020-08-01`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oh, I think I speed-read the question missing the last line.  Apologies

Comment: The issue wasn't with zero indexed months in the Date object, but that I assumed that the output would have zero indexed months too @HereticMonkey

Comment: Thanks @AnuragSrivastava, solved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output

```
2020-08-31T23:00:00.000Z
```

is ISO format, and the `Z` shows the date is in UTC. When you call the `Date` constructor, it is using your browser timezone by default, which I can assume is `+01:00`. Moreover, month indice in the constructor is zero-based.

If what you want is the beginning of the month in UTC, you can do:

```
d = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 8, 01))
d.toISOString()
"2020-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I get what you're saying - I was reading the output date with zero indexed months in mind although it shouldn't be read like that. And yeah, the timezone was confusing me slightly too. Thanks for your help

Comment: This answer is the same as in the identified duplicate and should not be marked as the answer...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
new Date(2020, 7, 1)
```

because date object is count from 0-11 no 1-12