# gantt chart plot wrong date on xAxis

Tags: angular, highcharts, gantt-chart

I want to display the progress in year in 2021. So the start point is 2021-1-1, and the end point is 2021-12-31.

The main code is:

```
xAxis: {
  min: Date.UTC(2021, 1, 1),
  max: Date.UTC(2021, 12, 31)
},
```

However it plots from Feb, 2021 to Jan, 2022.

Please see the [Stackblitz demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-gantt-v3w9xk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I found the answer,
[Javascript Date.UTC() function is off by a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507619/javascript-date-utc-function-is-off-by-a-month)

**this is due to months being listed as 0-11 range.**

Answer (score 0):

Array's start at 0, so does the month array. Which means month 1 is February and not January which is kind of mindbreaking though. You probably want to change it to:

```
xAxis: {
  min: Date.UTC(2021, 0, 1),
  max: Date.UTC(2021, 11, 31)
},
```

Comment: I think that it might be UTC thing. If you run the code for today's date `let utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 5, 19));
console.log(JSON.stringify(utcDate));`, then it prints tomorrow date. But now sure how to deal with it.

Comment: It prints "2021-06-19T00:00:00.000Z" for me...

Comment: So my question is why there is one day difference. If we understand that then we can set the value correctly rather than guess it.

Comment: It prints the 19th of June, the difference is a month, not a day (year-month-date).